# Disable render cache for a node type

Tags: theming, 8, caching

Is there a way to disable the render cache, which caches all the nodes by default, for a particular content type `X`.

I know we can disable the render cache site wide by commenting out

```
$settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = ‘cache.backend.null’;
```

in `settings.local.php`. But this is not a ideal approach for me as I need to disable the render cache only for a particular node type.

Also, I need to disable the cache for both Authenticated and Anonymous users for the content type `X`.

Any pointers on the same would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `Also, I need to disable the cache for both Authenticated and Anonymous users.` - basically, you have no caching at all, at which point the render cache is moot.

Comment: To what end? What is your goal?

Comment: @Kevin I meant this under the context of disabling the cache for both anonymous and authenticated users for a content type `X`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Like you said disabling the render cache site wide is not a good idea. If you need this for one content type you can do this in a view alter hook.

If you want to disable caching for authenticated and anonymous users you have to set cache max-age = 0 and trigger the kill switch for the internal page cache:

```
function MYMODULE_node_view_alter(array &$build, Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display) {
  if ($entity->bundle() == 'article') {
    $build['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
    \Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
  }
}
```

The same can be implemented in a theme in a preprocess hook.

Comment: Thank you @4k4 for the detailed answer! This was exactly what I wanted to do. Cheers :)