# Clear entity cache before render

Tags: hooks, caching

I secured some file in an s3 bucket using s3fs.
My problem is : the "Expires" argument send to build the file URI is not reset each time the object is call in my API.

time doesn't change if I don't clear the cache with drush

```
$expires = time() + 10;
```

So I tried to use hook_entity_view :

```
if ($entity->bundle() === 'my_bundle') {
    foreach ($entity->getCacheTags() as $tag) {
      $tags[] = $tag;
    }
  }
```

Doesn't work

```
Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entityType)->resetCache();
```

Nop

```
\Drupal::service('cache.render')->deleteAll();
\Drupal::service('cache.entity')->deleteAll();
\Drupal::service('cache.data')->deleteAll();
```

deleteAll or invalidateAll, none of it work.

```
drupal_flush_all_caches();
```

Nothing, I'm starting to think I have config problem...
If someone can save me !

#### UPDATE

It seems hook_entity_load works with my API, it clear the cache correctly.
The problem remains when i'm trying to watch the content in my Drupal website, in the content view.

Comment: So you want to disable caching for `my_bundle`? Then see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/232607/disable-render-cache-for-a-node-type

Comment: I can't figure out what exactly your problem is. Nor do I understand the context of where any of your code snippets are used. Can you please update your question. Can you more clearly define what you mean by "My problem is : the "Expires" argument send to build the file URI is not reset each time the object is call in my API."? Can you also explain what entity is in your code examples? What's the relationship between the s3 file and $entity. Also, where is any of this code being called from.

Comment: @4k4 Thx it fix my last render problem :)

Comment: @sonfd I just updated my question. Everything is ok now

Answer (score 0):

Ok everything is fixed, there were 2 points :

- Clean the cache when the media 'masterclass_private_video' is called, so the request to AWS s3 has the correct "Expires" timestamp when call by my VueJs API.
- Clean the render cache of the content view in my drupal backend.

Clean the media cache for the API :

```php
function mymodule_entity_load(array $entities, $entity_type_id)
{
  $tags = [];
  foreach ($entities as $entity) {
    if ($entity->bundle() === 'masterclass_private_video') {
      foreach ($entity->getCacheTags() as $tag) {
        $tags[] = $tag;
      }
    }
  }

  if (!empty($tags)) {
    Cache::invalidateTags($tags);
  }
}
```

Clean the page cache :

```php
function mymodule_node_view_alter(array &$build, Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display)
{
  if ($entity->bundle() === 'masterclass' || $entity->bundle() === 'masterclass_chapter') {
    $build['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
    \Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
  }
}
```

To be clear, the goal is to reset the $expires, so the AWS s3 works :

```php
function mymodule_s3fs_url_settings_alter(array &$url_settings, $s3_file_path)
{
  $split = explode('/', $s3_file_path);

  if (in_array('private', $split)) {
    $file_path = getenv('AWS_CLOUDFRONT_ENDPOINT') . $s3_file_path;

    $expires = time() + 86400;
    $private_key_filename = '/var/www/my-drupal/keys/pk-cloudfront.pem';
    $key_pair_id = getenv('AWS_S3_KEY_ID');

    $canned_policy_getters = Drupal::service('mymodule.aws.signature')
      ->getCannedPolicyGetters($file_path, $private_key_filename, $key_pair_id, $expires);

    $url_settings['custom_GET_args'] = $canned_policy_getters;
  }
}
```